# Replacing the output of one method into the output of another method

Tags: java, file, replace

So I have this method that should read a file and detect if the character after the symbol is a number or a word. If it is a number, I want to delete the symbol in front of it, translate the number into binary and replace it in the file. If it is a word, I want to set the characters to number 16 at first, but then, if another word is used, I want to add the 1 to the original number.

Here's the input that i'm using:

Here's my method:

```
    try {
       ReadFile files = new ReadFile(file.getPath());
       String[] anyLines = files.OpenFile();

        int i;


    int wordValue = 16;

// to keep track words that are already used
Map<String, Integer> wordValueMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

for (String line : anyLines) {

if (!line.startsWith("@")) {
    continue;
}

line = line.substring(1);

Integer binaryValue = null;

if (line.matches("\\d+")) {
    binaryValue = Integer.parseInt(line);
}
else if (line.matches("\\w+")) {
    binaryValue = wordValueMap.get(line);



    // if the map doesn't contain the word value, then assign and store it
    if (binaryValue == null) {
        binaryValue = wordValue;
        wordValueMap.put(line, binaryValue);
        ++wordValue;
    }
}

   // --> I want to replace with this 
   System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(binaryValue));


}


        for (i=0; i<anyLines.length; i++) {

       // --> Here are a bunch of instructions that replace certain strings - they are the lines after @ symbols <--
       // --> I'm not going to list them ... <--

            System.out.println(anyLines[i]);
```

So the question is, how do I replace those lines that start with ("@" line-by-line), in order?

I basically want the output to look like this:

```
101
1110110000010000 
10000
1110001100001000 
10001
1110101010001000 
10001
1111000010001000 
10000
1110001110001000 
10010
1110001100000110 
10011
1110101010000111 
10010
1110101010000111
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't quite understand the logic. If you are simply trying to replace all the @ symbols in order, why not read all the numbers into a `List` in order, until you see an @ symbol. Then you can start replacing them in order from that `List` (or `Queue` since you want first in first out). Does that satisfy your requirements?

If you must keep the `wordValueMap`, the code below should loop through the lines after you have populated the `wordValueMap` and write them to the console. It uses the same logic that you used to populate the map in the first place and outputs the values that should be replaced.

```
boolean foundAt = false;
for (i=0; i<anyLines.length; i++) {

  // --> Here are a bunch of instructions that replace certain strings - they are the lines after @ symbols <--
  // --> I'm not going to list them ... <--

  if (anyLines[i].startsWith("@")) {
    foundAt = true;
    String theLine = anyLines[i].substring(1);
    Integer theInt = null;
    if (theLine.matches("\\d+")) {
      theInt = Integer.parseInt(theLine);
    }
    else {
      theInt = wordValueMap.get(anyLines[i].substring(1));
    }

    if(theInt!=null) {
      System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(theInt));
    }
    else {
      //ERROR
    }
  }
  else if(foundAt) {
    System.out.println(anyLines[i]);
  }
}
```

When I run this loop, I get the output you were looking for from your question:

```
101
1110110000010000 
10000
1110001100001000 
10001
1110101010001000 
10001
1111000010001000 
10000
1110001110001000 
10010
1110001100000110 
10011
1110101010000111 
10010
1110101010000111
```

I hope this helps, but take a look at my question above to see if you can do this in a more straight forward manner.

Comment: Thanks, but what about if there's a word after the @ symbol?

Comment: I used the same input that you provided above (the first code block that you displayed).

Comment: Yeah, but that's System.out.println - and there are 2 of them - one for the @ letter or @ digit and one for the original file with the modified instructions.

Comment: @bamana, how would I use Queue (or what is the general format for a Queue)?

Comment: I removed your original `System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(binaryValue));` and the second loop will print all the values you need. You should be able to use a `Queue` from here: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html - using the `offer()` and `poll()` methods and use a `LinkedList` as the implementation.